# TinyMCE Image class issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I have an issue with TinyMCE.

I added the "Image" plugin and the "image_class_list" settings for set the class.
When i try to edit the image, i can't click on Class Field.

This is my JS:

```
tinymce.init(
{ 
    selector:'#descrizione',
    height: 500,
      plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table paste imagetools wordcount"
      ],
      toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
      content_css: [
        '//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,300i,400,400i',
      ],
    image_class_list: [
        {title: 'Responsive', value: 'img-fluid'}
    ],
    images_upload_url: 'ajax/uploadFoto.php',
    automatic_uploads: false,
    setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('change', function () {
            tinymce.triggerSave();
        });
    }

});
```

[image]

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have some sort of CSS interfering with the dialog as I don't get a horizontal purple scollbar in that dialog at all and the class field shows up just fine even when using one class option as your configuration does.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in CSS, other css file has display:none in the select, i fixed it adding a class with display block!